# Redondear y mostrar decimales C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math

Tengo lo siguiente, valor1 = 50.012478, quiero redondearlo a un (1) decimal, el Math.Round() lo redondea y muestra 50 pero yo necesito que se muestre en pantalla 50.0 Al igual con valor2 = 45.09874 redondear a dos decimales, necesito que se muestre 45.10. Mi código es:

```
        double valor1 = 50.012478;
        double valor2 = 45.098741;

        Console.WriteLine("valor 1: {0}", Math.Round(valor1, 1));
        Console.WriteLine("valor 2: {0}", Math.Round(valor2, 2));

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

otra forma es usar [cadena de formato estandar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN), aqui tienes mas ejemplos , le puse N1
porque son las cantidad de decimales que quieres

[image: resultado],

```
 double valor1 = 50.012478;

 var resultado = valor1.ToString("N1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Con un simple `.ToString("FormatoQueDeseas")` lo tendrías:

```
double valor1 = 50.012478;
double valor2 = 45.098741;

Console.WriteLine("valor 1: {0}", Math.Round(valor1, 1).ToString("#.0"));
Console.WriteLine("valor 2: {0}", Math.Round(valor2, 2).ToString("#.#0"));
```

En la [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) puedes ver que si deseas añadir un formato puedes hacerlo al convertirlo a string, por ejemplo si deseas conservar los valores que tiene, usa `#` y 0 en donde desees añadir el 0 extra. También te sirve para cualquier formato númerico, como por ejemplo:

```
int numero = 1234567;
string s = numero .ToString("#,##0");
//o también
string s = String.Format("Tu número formateado {0:#,##0}", numero );
```