# Truncar un numero decimal para que no redondee el valor decimal

Tags: c#

Trabajo con C# VS 20019

Estoy dando formato a un numero `218.364610615212` por parámetro le indico cuantos decimales debe de llevar

```
var valorFormateado =
               resultado2.ToString($"N{indicadorDecimal}", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-PE"));
```

**El resultado es 218.4 y lo que espero es 218.3**

Con este código `$"N{indicadorDecimal}"` obtengo `N1`, `N2`, `N3`, etc dependiendo del valor que contenga `indicadorDecimal`

Necesito en este caso

```
decimal resultado3 = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(valorFormateado) * 10) / 10;
```

Pero el problema es que obtengo los decimales con `$"N{indicadorDecimal}"` habría alguna manera de transformarlo a `10`, `100`, etc.

Comment: Tal vez, [Esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430990/redondear-y-mostrar-decimales-c/430992#430992) es lo que quieres

Comment: @NicolasOñate la cantidad de decimales la trae esta variable `indicadorDecimal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te coloco un metodo que he implementado para realizar esta tarea, usando un procedimiento más cercano al metodo de fuerza bruta, pero que a mi me da buenos resultados.

```
  private decimal Truncar(decimal valor, int numerodeDecimales)
    {
        string valstring = valor.ToString();
        int indexPto = valstring.IndexOf(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        if (numerodeDecimales < valstring.Length - indexPto - 1)
            valstring = valstring.Remove(indexPto + 1 + numerodeDecimales);
        decimal.TryParse(valstring, out decimal dec);
        return dec;
    }
```

El parametro `valor` es el `decimal` que quieres truncar y el parametro `numerodeDecimales` es la cantidad de posiciones significativas que quieres mostrar despues del punto.

Edito la respuesta para enrriquecerla con otra variante, en este caso implementada para formatear el decimal a dos lugares despues del separador decimal.

```
   private decimal TruncarDosDecimales(decimal valor)
    {
        string valstring = valor.ToString("#.##");
        //Si se desea formaear a 1 lugar decimal
        //string valstring = valor.ToString("#.#");
        decimal.TryParse(valstring, out decimal dec);
        return dec;
    }
```

Comment: No esta truncando el valor que le envio es 1 decimal, pueden ser 2, 3, etc

Comment: @PedroÁvila No entiendo tu comentario. El primer procedimiento está hecho para formatear un decimal a una cantidad de posiciones significativas despues del punto, que debes especificar como parametro `numerodeDecimales` al invocar el procedimiento. En el segundo procedimiento, se formatea solo a dos lugares decimales, si deseas solo uno descomenta la linea `string valstring = valor.ToString("#.#");` y elimina la anterior.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var tmp = Math.Pow(10, numeroDeDecimales);
return Math.Truncate(numeroATruncar * tmp) / tmp
```

Comment: Estoy trabajando con decimales y en tu código 10 es double?

Comment: Que representa 10 el numero como tal? la parte entera?

Comment: @PedroÁvila es el número al que se desea elevar una potencia. En tu caso 10^1.