# Tabla de amortizacion de un prestamo bancario C#

Tags: c#

Gente, realize esta tabla de amortizacion, pero me pasa, que en el ultimo mes, por una cuestion de que faltan unas decimas al restar la el ultimo saldo mensual y la amortizacion, queda en -5, esto lo puedo solucionar redondeando, como puedo hacer para redondear todos los ultimos valores que obtengo en el ciclo for? quisiera que los resultados quedaran solo con dos numeros despues de la coma decimal

```
        long ValorPrestamo;//valor del préstamo
        double InteresDeuda;//valor del interes mensual
        double NumeroMesesPrestamo;//meses para pagar el préstamo
        double Mensualidad;//mensualidad o renta
        

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor del prestamo");
        ValorPrestamo = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor del interes");
        InteresDeuda = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de meses");
        NumeroMesesPrestamo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        double InteresMensual = 0;
        double AmortizacionMensual = 0;
        double SaldoRestanteMensual = ValorPrestamo;

        //calcular la mensualidad
        Mensualidad = (ValorPrestamo * InteresDeuda) / (1 - (Math.Pow(1 + InteresDeuda, -NumeroMesesPrestamo)));

        //variables para amortización, intereses mensual, saldo mensual
        Console.WriteLine("El valor de la mensualidad es:" + Mensualidad);
        Console.WriteLine("Meses\t\tMensualidad\t\tInteres\t\tAmortizacion\t\tSaldo");

        
        for (int k = 1; k <= NumeroMesesPrestamo; k++)
        {
            //Calculo Amortizacion, Intereses y el saldo que queda cada mes
            InteresMensual = SaldoRestanteMensual * InteresDeuda;
            AmortizacionMensual = Mensualidad - InteresMensual;
            SaldoRestanteMensual = SaldoRestanteMensual - AmortizacionMensual;
            Console.WriteLine(k + "\t" + Mensualidad +"\t" + InteresMensual +"\t" + AmortizacionMensual +"\t" + SaldoRestanteMensual );
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los nombres de las variables deberian indicar a que se refieren.. No se que es AM o R o IM o A o i... (estan definidos alla arriba, pero si A es el valor del prestamo, porque la variable no se llama ValorPrestamo?)... y luego definis SM dentro del bucle, con lo cual siempre tiene el ultimo valor (que igual lo tendria, porque es la unica cuenta que haces para calcular SM que no se que es)

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, despues de mucho pensar creo que pude lograrlo, gracias por tus recomendaciones me ayudaron muchisimo, voy a actualizar el codigo y la pregunta, asi que si puedes contestarme mi nueva duda te agradeceria muchisimo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430990/redondear-y-mostrar-decimales-c revisa esto. Quizás te ayude.

Comment: @Mateo Muchisimas gracias! ahora si pude solucionar el problema!

Comment: No uses doble para valores que quieres que sean monedas.. usa decimal...